# How to increase the speed of a large for loop in C#

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

Right now I'm trying to run very large for loops for some task, nearly about 300000+ items. I tried using `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach`, but it do not seems to be working that fast as required.  My code is as below:

```
public List<DailyUserStaticticeModel> QueryDailyStoreUserData2(List<StoreUserHisStaticticeModel> storeUsers, int brandId, DateTime? startTime, DateTime? endTime, Boolean isAll = false)
{
    List<DailyUserStaticticeModel> list = new List<DailyUserStaticticeModel>();

    var storeUserRadixCodes = storeUsers.Select(n => n.StoreUser.StoreUserRadixCode).Distinct().ToList();
    var storeUserHisIds = storeUsers.Select(n => n.StoreUser.Id).Distinct().ToList();

    var date_diff = endTime.Value.Subtract(startTime.Value).Days;



    for (var i = 0; i < date_diff; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < storeUserRadixCodes.Count; j++)
        {
            DailyUserStaticticeModel model = new DailyUserStaticticeModel()
            {
                CurrentDate = startTime.Value.AddDays(i)
            };

            var store_user = storeUsers.FirstOrDefault(t => t.StoreUser.StoreUserRadixCode == storeUserRadixCodes[j]);

            model.StoreUser = store_user.StoreUser;

            list.Add(model);
        }
    }


    var order_list = _dbContext.DB.Queryable<t_StoreUserOrderHis>()
                               .Where(a => a.ShopGuideBrandId == brandId)
                               .WhereIF(startTime.HasValue, a => a.CreateTime >= startTime)
                               .WhereIF(endTime.HasValue, a => a.CreateTime < endTime)
                               .Select(a => new t_StoreUserOrderHis
                               {
                                   StoreUserRadixCode = a.StoreUserRadixCode,
                                   CreateTime = a.CreateTime.Date,
                                   OrderAmount = a.OrderAmount.Value,
                                   ReturnOrderAmount = a.ReturnOrderAmount,
                                   RealPrice = a.RealPrice,
                                   OrderNumber = a.OrderNumber,
                                   ReturnOrderNumber = a.ReturnOrderNumber
                               }).ToList();

    var share_visit_list = _dbContext.DB.Queryable<t_StoreUserShareVisitHis>().Where(a => a.BrandID == brandId)
                                           .WhereIF(startTime.HasValue, a => a.CreateTime >= startTime)
                                           .WhereIF(endTime.HasValue, a => a.CreateTime < endTime)
                                           .Select(a => new t_StoreUserShareVisitHis
                                           {
                                               StoreUserRadixCode = a.StoreUserRadixCode,
                                               CreateTime = a.CreateTime,
                                               OpenId = a.OpenId
                                           }).ToList();

    var recruit_list = _dbContext.DB.Queryable<t_StoreUserRecruitHis>().Where(a => a.BrandId == brandId)
                                   .Select(a => new t_StoreUserRecruitHis
                                   {
                                       StoreUserRadixCode = a.StoreUserRadixCode,
                                       CreateTime = a.CreateTime
                                   }).ToList();

    var external_list = _dbContext.DB.Queryable<t_ExternalContactsInfo>().Where(a => a.BrandID == brandId)
                                            .Select(a => new
                                            {
                                                StoreUserHisId = a.StoreUserHisID,
                                                CreateTime = a.CreateTime
                                            }).ToList();

    var recruit_mp_list = _dbContext.DB.Queryable<t_RecruitMPUserHis>().Where(a => a.BrandID == brandId)
                                     .Select(a => new
                                     {
                                         StoreUserHisId = a.StoreUserHisID,
                                         CreateTime = a.CreateTime
                                     }).ToList();

    var relation_his_list = _dbContext.DB.Queryable<t_StoreUserRelationHis>().Where(a => a.BrandID == brandId && a.DeleteTime == null)
                                            .Where(a => a.BindType != 2 || (a.BindType == 2 && a.ExpireTime > DateTime.Now))
                                            .Select(a => new
                                            {
                                                ShareBindTime = a.ShareBindTime,
                                                ShareBy = a.ShareBy
                                            }).ToList();
```

The list has more than 300000 items, each execution will waste 100 ~ 200ms, But for a large loop, the time is too long, what can I do to increase the speed?

```
    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = list[i];

        var orders = order_list.Where(a => a.StoreUserRadixCode == item.StoreUser.StoreUserRadixCode && a.CreateTime.Date == item.CurrentDate.Date);
        item.RealSale = orders.Sum(a => a.RealPrice);
        item.Num = orders.Sum(a => a.OrderNumber);
        item.OrderNum = orders.Count();
        item.Sale = orders.Sum(a => a.OrderAmount.Value);
        item.ReturnOrderNum = orders.Sum(a => a.ReturnOrderNumber);
        item.Refund = orders.Sum(a => a.ReturnOrderAmount);


        var share_visit = share_visit_list.Where(a => a.CreateTime.Date == item.CurrentDate.Date && a.StoreUserRadixCode == item.StoreUser.StoreUserRadixCode);
        item.PagePV = share_visit.Count();
        item.PageUV = share_visit.Distinct(a => a.OpenId).Count();


        var recruit_all_list = recruit_list.Where(a => a.StoreUserRadixCode == item.StoreUser.StoreUserRadixCode);
        var recruit_date_list = recruit_all_list.Where(a => a.CreateTime.Date == item.CurrentDate.Date);

        item.RecruitmentTotal = recruit_all_list.Count();
        item.RecruitmentNum = recruit_date_list.Count();


        var external_contact_list = external_list.Where(a => a.StoreUserHisId == item.StoreUser.Id);
        var external_current_list = external_contact_list.Where(a => a.CreateTime.Date == item.CurrentDate.Date);

        item.QyExternalNum = external_current_list.Count();
        item.QyExternalTotal = external_contact_list.Count();


        var mp_list = recruit_mp_list.Where(a => a.StoreUserHisId == item.StoreUser.Id);

        var mp_current_list = mp_list.Where(a => a.CreateTime.Date == item.CurrentDate.Date);

        item.RecruitMPNum = mp_current_list.Count();
        item.RecruitMPTotal = mp_list.Count();


        var relation_his = relation_his_list.Where(a => a.ShareBy == item.StoreUser.StoreUserRadixCode && a.ShareBindTime.Value.Date == item.CurrentDate.Date);

        item.RelationHisNum = relation_his.Count();
    }

    list = list.OrderBy(t => t.CurrentDate).ToList();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: find out what's slow  first, you will need to run a profiler on it, you can use the jetbrains one, dotTrace for 30days for free.    I can see lots of things that aren't optimal, but not sure what is specifically slowing you down

Comment: The main reason is that the loop needs to be executed too many times,The list has more than 300000 items ,but each cycle only takes about 200 milliseconds.And it seems not able to optimizing the code in this loop, So i want to know is there any way to solve this.

Comment: 300000 is a tiny number for a computer, 200 milliseconds is a long time for a single iteration of a loop, see my first comment.  Your question doesn't make sense until you show us what is slow, there's lots of ways to solve problems like that...... if you know what is going slow.

Comment: Consider making `storeUsers` a `Dictionary`